# XmlReader Other Options

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am currently working on an application for the company I work for. Part of this application deals with discrepancy reporting and sending emails out when a new discrepancy number has been created. First, it is important to realize that I am redeveloping this application from VB.NET to C#. In the old application the developer chose to read an XML file for a few email addresses. I've read to use alternate options unless the XML file is full of information. This is not intended to be an opinionated question and sorry if this sounds like one. However, I am looking for the correct way of doing this. Should these email addresses be kept in a database table for easy adding/deleting or is there a more standardized way to do this? Please find the current code below.

```
public void PrepareEmail(string subject, string message)
{

    if (MessageBox.Show(@"Are you sure you want to save and send Discrepancy Report: " + tbxDRNumber.Text + @"?\n Click YES to save\n Click NO to cancel", @"Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

        SendEmail(subject, message);
    }
}

public Array AddEmail()
{

    string[] dRemail = { "", "", "" };

    if (File.Exists(@"\\fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager\DREmailAddresses.xml"))
    {
        XmlReader emailDocument = new XmlTextReader(@"\\fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager\DREmailAddresses.xml");

        while (emailDocument.Read())
        {
            var type = emailDocument.NodeType;

            switch (type)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (emailDocument.Name == "DRCreatedAddEmail")
                    {
                        dRemail[0] = emailDocument.ReadInnerXml();
                    }
                    if (emailDocument.Name == "DRActionNeededAddEmail")
                    {
                        dRemail[1] = emailDocument.ReadInnerXml();
                    }
                    if (emailDocument.Name == "DRPendingAddEmail")
                    {
                        dRemail[2] = emailDocument.ReadInnerXml();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(@"The file: 'DREmailAddresses.xml' was not found at: \\fs01\Applications\EMS-Manager");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return dRemail;
}

public void SendEmail(string subjectText, string bodyText)
{

    string[] email = (string[])AddEmail();
    //object oOutlook = default(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application);
    var oMessage = default(MailItem);
    Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application"));

    if (subjectText == "New Discrepancy Created. DR" + tbxDRNumber.Text + "  ")
    {
        oMessage.To = email[0];
        oMessage.Subject = subjectText;
        oMessage.HTMLBody = bodyText;

        try
        {
            oMessage.Send();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Send Failed with error: " + e);
            throw;
        }
    }
    else if (subjectText == tbxDRNumber.Text + " - Action Needed")
    {
        oMessage.To = email[1];
        oMessage.Subject = subjectText;
        oMessage.HTMLBody = bodyText;

        try
        {
            oMessage.Send();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Send Failed with error: " + e);
            throw;
        }
    }
    else if (subjectText == tbxDRNumber.Text + "DR Pending Approval")
    {
        oMessage.To = email[2];
        oMessage.Subject = subjectText;
        oMessage.HTMLBody = bodyText;

        try
        {
            oMessage.Send();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Send Failed with error: " + e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work?  Leave it be and move on to other higher priority options.  And please take the time to format your code - thanks :)

Comment: I did format the code. I was under the impression that all must be tabbed in 4 spaces. It works, however I cannot gain access to the file. It says it doesn't exist but yet it does.

Comment: Any data that is used by more than one person at the same time should be stored in a database since file sharing on Windows can cause problems.  A database base is designed to handle conflicts when more than one user attempts to use same data at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't necessarily anything wrong with flat file configuration files. It really depends on your use case. How often do the emails in the file change? How many entries are there? Do users of the application edit the list? Are there any complex rules where different addresses will get sent different emails?

If this just a simple mailing list that doesn't change often it's probably fine to use the xml file. You could also just create an email distribution list to send to instead, like ApplicationDiscrepancyReport. That way you can just manage the recipients in active directory. If you stick with the XML email addresses, at the very least I would try to get rid of the hardcoded path to the xml file located on your file share.

If the email addresses change a lot, and are changed by users of the application, I would recommend moving this to a SQL database. If the recipients list is changing frequently you may want to add tracking of when these addresses get edited as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. The email addresses do not change a lot, however I am thinking ahead. There are people who will be retiring at some point in that list or quit for whatever reason. My idea was to be able to give managers an easy way of updating that list. There are different cases in which the distribution list is changed depending on what the user has entered into the form.